# How can I use a csv file to calculate the average rating of several people in a ranking post?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

There is this community leaderboard and I thought I'd try and take a crack at it. In this practice, I want to

1. Take the ratings between 1 to 10 people have chosen for each character in the google form as a multiple-choice answer, and then average them and stick them to each character.
2. Rank them according to those averages.

```python
import csv
import math
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import sys
from collections import Counter

def main():
   file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
   df = csv.DictReader(file)
   newf = list(df)
   gf = convert_to_float(newf)
   sf = pd.DataFrame(gf)
   answer = dict(sf.mean())
   print(answer)

def convert_to_float(lst):
   for b in lst:
    for a,x in b.items():
        if x.isnumeric:
            result = [dict([a,float(x)]) for a,x in b.items() for b in lst]
        else:
            result = [dict([a,x]) for a,x in b.items()]
    return result

main()
```

The problem is that in each response the people who haven't watched a character haven't rated them, and I'm having trouble converting that space into something that won't interfere with my averages. By just using the pandas framework alone, I'm getting illegible answers like `1.241342432e+79`, etc. The easiest way for me to do this task is to average everything in excel and then put that final column in a sorting algorithm, but I want to try and code this.

Comment: Worth noting that Pandas can read CSV files natively. Would shave about ten lines off of your program: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: It would be nice/helpful to provide some sample inputs/outputs - so others can easily help you (to confirm).